# Unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__

Tags: python

The initial problem I started with is:

> Write a function so that the main program below can be replaced by the simpler code that calls function `mph_and_minutes_to_miles()`.
>
> ```
> miles_per_hour = float(input())
> minutes_traveled = float(input())
> hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60.0
> miles_traveled = hours_traveled * miles_per_hour
>
> print('Miles: {:f}'.format(miles_traveled))
> ```
>
> Sample output with inputs: `70.0 100.0`
> `Miles: 116.666667`

The code I have written for it so far is:

```
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour,minutes_traveled):
    hours_traveled=minutes_traveled/60.0
    miles_traveled=hours_traveled*miles_per_hour
    print('Miles: {:f}' .format(miles_traveled))
    miles_per_hour = float(input())
    minutes_traveled = float(input())

print('Miles: {:f}'.format(mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled)))
```

The error message it produces is:

```
Exited with return code 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print('Miles: {:f}'.format(mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled)))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

After reviewing the code a few times I still can not seem to figure out how to rectify it.

Comment: You need to add `return minutes_traveled` line at the end of your `mph_and_minutes_to_miles` function so that it can return the value it compute. Otherwise, it will just return `None` as shown in the error message

Answer (score 1):

It's because your function doesn't actually return anything at the moment! Or more specifically, it returns `None`, which can't be formatted.

You can try something like this:

```py
def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled):
    hours_traveled = minutes_traveled/60.0
    miles_traveled = hours_traveled*miles_per_hour
    print('Miles: {:f}' .format(miles_traveled))
    return miles_traveled


miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())
answer = mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, minutes_traveled)

print('Miles: {:f}'.format(answer))
```

Comment: Thank you!! I honestly can not believe I overlooked that!

Comment: No worries, it happens!